# CW-decomposition of quotient space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

Let $X$ be the space that results form $D^3$ by identifying points on the boundary $S^2$ that are mapped to one another by a $180°$-rotation about some fixed axis.

I want to calculate the cellular homology of $X$,  but I have trouble finding a suitable CW-decomopistion. How does one generally approach finding a CW-decomopostion of a CW-complex, especially if they are more complex?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: In low-dimensional topology, there's a concept of fake 3-cells, which are compact and contractible manifolds that nevertheless aren't 3-cells. This leads inevitably to the concept of fake fake 3-cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general way of finding a CW-decomposition of an arbitrary space. In this specific example, note that $S^2$ with the prescribed identifications is simply $S^2$. Then in order to obtain our space $X$ from that we must glue in a 3-cell. Try to convince yourself that the attaching map of the $3$-cell is precisely the suspension of the degree $2$ map $$f:S^1\to S^1\\ z\mapsto z^2.$$
So we can give $X$ the cell structure of one $0$-cell, one $2$-cell and one $3$-cell where the $3$-cell is attached via a degree $2$ map. (The suspension of a degree $k$ map has degree $k$ - prove this, it's easy.)

This provides all the necessary ingredients to compute the (cellular) homology of this space.

Comment: Sorry, I'm late. I've got: $H_0(X)= \mathbb{Z}, H_1(X)= \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, H_2(X) = H_3(X) = 0$

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint: first find a CW decomposition of $S^2$ which is invariant under the $180^\circ$ rotation.